# Calling Groovy classes from Java EE + adding to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, groovy

**Background**

Hello, I'm new to Java EE. I'm following [this tutorial](https://milkedeek.wordpress.com/2012/08/20/groovy-and-tomcat-pt1/) that outlines how to call a groovy class from a java project. Reason for doing this is a lot of pre-existing code I have built is written in groovy, and is fairly extensible for what I would like to do.

**Context**

From a Java and Groovy perspective, the code works. However when firing up the tomcat server and opening `index.jsp`, I am not able to hit the code.

When looking at the `index.jsp` file, I see error: `cannot resolve variable` for `language`, `sentiment`, and `message`.

**Additional Information / Thoughts**

Could this be something to do with my dependencies?
I used `maven` to import `ant:ant-antlr:1.6.5`, `asm:asm-all:3.3.1`, `jstl:jstl:1.2`, `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.1`. Are they the wrong ones? Before adding dependencies, `Java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core` was not able to be found (obviously)

**Expected output**

Open a web browser and the page displays "I'm using java! that's okay.... I was called from groovy, Exciting"

**Actual Output**

I'm using ! That's

**Here's the code:**

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>I'm using <c:out value="${language}" />! That's <c:out value="${sentiment}" /></p>
<p><c:out value="${message}" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaServlet.java

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.getSession().setAttribute("language", "java");
        req.getSession().setAttribute("sentiment", "ok...");
        resp.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        req.getSession().setAttribute("message", main.message());
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JavaServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>JavaServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JavaServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/javacallinggroovy</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

main.groovy

```
class main {

    static def message() {
        "I was called from Groovy. Exciting, isn't it?"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add these in your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jsp-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That didn't work. Could Intellij have anything to do with it?